# How can I have a Map that all processes can access?

Tags: multithreading, erlang, elixir

I'm building a multithreaded web crawler.

I launch a thread that gets first `n` href links and parses some data. Then it should add those links to a Visited list that other threads can access and adds the data to a global map that will be printed when the program is done. Then the thread launches new `n` new threads all doing the same thing.

How can I setup a global list of Visited sites that all threads can access and a global map that all threads can also write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, erlang/elixir uses processes rather than threads.

Given a list of elements, a generic approach:

- An empty list called `processed` is saved to ets, dets, mnesia or some DB.
- The new list of elements is filtered against the `processed` list so the Task is not unnecessarily repeated.
- For each element of the filtered list, a task is run (which in turn spawns a process) and does some work on each element that returns a map of the required data. See the [Task module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Task.html) [Task.async/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Task.html#async/1) and [Task.yield_many/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Task.html#yield_many/2) could be useful.
- Once all the tasks have returned or yielded,

  1. all the maps or parts of the data in the maps are merged and can be persisted if/as required/appropriate.
  2. the elements whose tasks did not crash or timeout are added to the `processed` list in the DB.
- Tasks which crash or timeout could be handled differently.

Answer (score 8):

You can't share data between processes. That doesn't mean that you can't share information.

the usual way is  either to use a special process (a server) in charge of this job: maintain a state; in your case the list of visited links.

Another way is to use [ETS](http://erlang.org/erldoc) (or Mnesia the database build upon ETS) which is designed to share information between processes.

Comment: Typically, a process that simply wraps some state is based on Agent. You can send it messages to query for the state or get it. See http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/agent.html for the documentation (yes, I know link-pasting is frowned upon on SO, hence just a comment :-))